# Is it possible to check that a simple expression will always return true?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, lambda, expression-trees

And I mean this in the easiest way. Say you have a function with the following signature:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateExpression<T>(string value)
{
    // ...
}
```

Usually it will create a more complex expression of some sort, but if the `value` is `null` the method should return a constant, always true expression. In other words:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateExpression<T>(string value)
{
    if(value == null)
        return x => true;

    // ...
}
```

Is this something I can create a unit test for? That when I send in `null` as the value, I do get back a constant true expression?

Comment: This sounds to me like a Halting-type problem, is which case it would be impossible for a general expression.

Comment: well, for a general expression, yes. But in this case, I know what value I send in, and in what case I should get back a simple "true". which should be a simple expression... at least pretty much as basic as it can get, I would say?

Comment: This is a bit confusing... What are you trying to test? The result of the function? Can you return an object, or a named function?

Comment: "If your brother looks like he's always answering yes to the question 'do you want another cookie?', will he always answer yes to that question"

Comment: Ok, the example was maybe not very good because of the TSource and TValue and selector and stuff. I'll simplify it. What I am trying to do exactly is to create a method that takes a range (a to b) and then creates an expression which checks that something (the selector) is between a and b. But if a and b are both null, it should just return true. Because in that case I consider the range to be an open range that covers everything. Hope that made some sense anyways... :p

Comment: Well, for a unit-test, you would then have to loop through everything and check that all the values make the expression return true. This is basically what unit tests are, with some known input, do you get a known output. It's much harder to say "without giving the expression input, can I analyze it to tell whether it will always give the right output"

Comment: Yes, so in this case I know what the method will get and what it should give back. It was just an issue of how to check that what I got back was what I wanted. Kind of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would be easy enough to test for *exactly* that expression (the body will be a `ConstantExpression` with value `true`). But in the general case? No - too complex.

```
static bool IsConstantTrue(LambdaExpression lambda)
{
    return lambda.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant
        && true.Equals(((ConstantExpression)lambda.Body).Value);
}
```

with

```
Expression<Func<SomeType, bool>> exp = x => true; // or some method that 
                                                  // returns a lambda expression
Assert.IsTrue(IsConstantTrue(exp));
```

Comment: That was what I was thinking of, yes. Could you make an example of how you'd write that test for an expression?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do so that I know of. However, if you're willing to refactor a bit:

```
class Sample<T>
{
    public static Func<T, bool> Identity = x => true;

    public static Func<T, bool> CreateExpression(string value)
    {
        if(value == "foo")
            return Identity;

        return x => value.Length % 2 == 0;
    }
}

class Test
{
    public void DoTest()
    {
        Debug.Assert(Sample<string>.CreateExpression("foo") == Sample<string>.Identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also a very good idea, but the method in question isn't part of a class where an identity like that would be good to have. Up-voting though, cause that might be useful some other time :)

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean be "simple" here? It's kind of a woolly term...

In general, the only thing we can seay is that this is yet another manifestation of the [**halting problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). Consider, how can you you determine the result of a function until all possible parameters, unless you actually run it under all possible parameters? Apart from being practically infeasible, you can't even guarantee a result because of the nature of the halting problem (you don't know the method will even terminate, or what path it may take in the indefinite future).

Comment: But when you have the expression tree, you can check if it is a constant expression or not. I suppose you should also be able to maybe even scan through the whole expression tree and check that incoming parameters are never really used or something. But that's just me thinking. Don't know enough about expression trees :p

Comment: Oh, in this case that it's just a constant, and there's no conditional logic/loops or anything, you should be safe. Wasn't sure that's what you mean though.

Comment: No worries. I'll leave this answer here just for theoretical justification if anyone wonders...